# Qual a diferença entre estas manipulações de strings em C

Tags: c, linux

Bom dia! Estou aprendendo **C** e tive uma dúvida na hora de utilizar strings, queria saber se existe **diferença** de utilizar esta forma:

```
char palavra[255];

    printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
    
    setbuf(stdin, 0); //limpar o buffer
    fgets(palavra, 255, stdin); // ler a string
    palavra[strlen(palavra)-1] = '\0';

    printf("%s", palavra);
```

para utilizar desta forma:

```
printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
    scanf("%s", palavra);
    printf("%s\n", palavra);
```

Desde já agradeço a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O segundo excerto não vai ler *espaços em branco*.

Ou melhor, ele vai achar que o espaço em branco é o terminador do `scanf`.

Se mais tarde, no programa, houver mais um `scanf`, o que vem após o espaço em branco anterior vai preencher este novo `scanf`.

Ou seja, a cada espaço em branco, você deixa uma string nova no buffer do teclado.

Comment: Ah entendi, mas na prática eu podeia usar qualquer um que não causaria um impacto?

Comment: O segundo causaria certo impacto, mas só se você tiver um `scanf` subsequente e você não digitar a barra de espaços.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!